# A third party repo against of a main one?! I want to install tor from its repository?

Tags: repository, tor

Installing tor from its repository, not from the universe Ubuntu repository! -> Here is the instruction: https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian (I done)

But when I run `sudo apt-get install tor`, it is connected to ubuntu repository! this installs the version which is located in Ubuntu repositories! I want the version which is in the below repository:

```
deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org raring main
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's because both repos have the same `tor` version, 0.2.3.25-1 for Ubuntu 13.04 (raring), so there's no reason to prefer one over other.

If you correctly set up the torproject repository, the output of `apt-cache policy tor` will tell you the available versions, from which repository they come and the candidate for installation.

Comment: hmm, yeam; I check your command and the versions are the same; However, how can I force apt-get to select torproject repository for future update? Does it always check for the newest version between both repositories to choose one of them for updating tor?

Comment: Yes, apt will automatically choose the newest version.

Comment: @deroot If the package isn't held back (look for **hold** in `apt-mark` [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/apt-mark.8.html)) `apt-get` will always try to install the newest version.